# Machine learning : learn feature value range for a classification

Tags: machine-learning, pattern-matching, linear-regression

Which domain the problem belongs to? Given a set of products some are classified as cheap and some not. The task is to determine the price range (probablistic) for cheap products ? Supervised classifiers arrive at a function and can classify a new instance but does not provide the range of feature values. This seems like a pattern recognition problem but I am not able to get which class of problems it belongs to.

Edit:
reading more about this, could this be a rule mining problem?

Comment: like how to find a pattern saying, all products with price <2000 are generally classified as cheap for 90% of the cases. This would be the output after learning over 100s of product features (say for example)

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something, but why not simply find under which price lie 90% of the cheap products in your sample? It sounds like a trivial data exploration problem, not a case for machine learning.

Comment: @DonReba Well price was one example, lets say we have 100 features of the product and the ask is to determine what set of feature(s) values constitute cheap(ness) of a product.

Comment: Isn't cheapness entirely determined by price? If you want to estimate appropriate price for a product from its features — that is a different problem.